# How to setup a minimization problem in GAMS

Tags: minimization, gams-math

This is probably a noob question, but I am trying to minimize the mean absolute error in GAMS.
Consider the following data in GAMS:

```
set Time /0 * 2/;

parameter y(Time),u(Time),v(Time),yhat(Time),MAE;

scalar
    alpha /0/
    beta /0/;

y("0")  = 24;
y("1")  = 23;
y("2")  = 26;
```

I want to do the following equation based on exponentiel smoothing (the equation is taking [from here](https://www.real-statistics.com/time-series-analysis/basic-time-series-forecasting/holt-linear-trend/)):

[image]

I can do that in GAMS with an loop:

```
u("0") = y("0");
v("0") = 0;

loop(Time,
    u(Time) = (alpha*y(Time))+(1-alpha)*(u(Time-1)-v(Time-1));
    v(Time) = beta*(u(Time)-u(Time-1))+(1-beta)*v(Time-1);
    yhat(Time) = u(Time-1)+v(Time-1);
);
```

From this I can calculate the mean absolute error:

```
set Timesub(Time) / 1 * 2 /;

MAE = sum(Timesub,abs(yhat(Timesub)-y(Timesub)))/2;
```

However, instead of assuming a value for alpha and beta, I want to minimize the value of MAE by changing the value in alpha and beta subject to the constraint that 0 < alpha <= 1.0 and 0 < beta <= 1.0.

But I am not sure how to setup this minimization problem in GAMS.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that your GAMS assignment for u has a bug (sign error).

In GAMS you have to "unroll" the loop and construct a large system of simultaneous equations. Using data from your reference, this can look like:

```
set
  t /t1*t15/
;

parameter y(t) 'data' /
 t1    3
 t2    5
 t3    9
 t4   20
 t5   12
 t6   17
 t7   22
 t8   23
 t9   51
 t10  41
 t11  56
 t12  75
 t13  60
 t14  75
 t15  88
/;


variables
   u(t),v(t),yhat(t),MAE
;
positive variables
   alpha, beta
   abserr(t)
;

alpha.up = 1;
beta.up = 1;


equations
  udef(t)
  vdef(t)
  pred(t)
  abs1(t)
  abs2(t)
  obj
;

u.fx("t1") = y("t1");
v.fx("t1") = 0;
yhat.fx("t1") = 0;

udef(t-1)..  u(t) =e= alpha*y(t)+(1-alpha)*(u(t-1)+v(t-1));
vdef(t-1)..  v(t) =e= beta*(u(t)-u(t-1))+(1-beta)*v(t-1);
pred(t-1)..  yhat(t) =e= u(t-1)+v(t-1);

abs1(t)$(ord(t)>1)..  -abserr(t) =l= yhat(t)-y(t);
abs2(t)$(ord(t)>1)..   yhat(t)-y(t) =l= abserr(t);

obj.. MAE =e= sum(t$(ord(t)>1),abserr(t))/(card(t)-1);

* initial point
alpha.l = 0.4;
beta.l = 0.7;

model m /all/;
option nlp=conopt;
solve m minimizing MAE using nlp;


parameter results(*,*);
results(t,'y') = y(t);
results(t,'u') = u.l(t);
results(t,'v') = v.l(t);
results(t,'yhat') = yhat.l(t);
results(t,'|e|') = abserr.l(t);
display results;
display alpha.l,beta.l,MAE.l;
```

The results look like:

```
----     73 PARAMETER results  

              y           u           v        yhat         |e|

t1        3.000       3.000
t2        5.000       3.428       0.370       3.000       2.000
t3        9.000       4.910       1.333       3.798       5.202
t4       20.000       9.184       3.878       6.243      13.757
t5       12.000      12.835       3.681      13.062       1.062
t6       17.000      16.620       3.771      16.516       0.484
t7       22.000      20.735       4.069      20.391       1.609
t8       23.000      24.418       3.735      24.803       1.803
t9       51.000      33.038       7.962      28.153      22.847
t10      41.000      41.000       7.962      41.000
t11      56.000      50.467       9.264      48.962       7.038
t12      75.000      62.996      12.089      59.731      15.269
t13      60.000      71.860       9.298      75.085      15.085
t14      75.000      79.841       8.159      81.158       6.158
t15      88.000      88.000       8.159      88.000


----     74 VARIABLE alpha.L               =        0.214  
            VARIABLE beta.L                =        0.865  
            VARIABLE MAE.L                 =        6.594
```

This is a bit better than reported in [link](https://www.real-statistics.com/time-series-analysis/basic-time-series-forecasting/holt-linear-trend/). The reason is that this is actually a non-convex problem. I verified that CONOPT actually found the global optimal solution (verification by using a global solver).